# Postioning 5 dots from the same div overlapping an image?

Tags: javascript, arrays, slider, position

Hi im trying to get a row of dots to overlap a image to show a route, i can position one dot with this code:

```
var dotPosition_X = new Array();
var dotPosition_Y = new Array();

dotPosition_X[1] = 10;
dotPosition_Y[1] = 40;

$("#reddot").offset({ top: dotPosition_Y[1], left: dotPosition_X[1]});

});
```

this positions the dot exactly over the image but i need it to repeat without me making mutiple divs for the same variable?

is there anyway around this?

and if working could i use a slider to go through the array of dots to change it from blue to red when changing the value of the slide?

Comment: Do you want to clone the dot?

Comment: if you want 5 dots, you need 5 objects, they can for example be div:s or img:s

Comment: Yes i would like to clone the same dot, mutilpe times in different postions (following the route)

Answer (score 1):

One way or another, you'll need to make multiple elements. If you need individual control over each dot, then you'll probably want to generate them all with unique IDs. If you only ever need to manipulate them as a group, you can get away without the IDs.

With jQuery, it's pretty easy to generate elements on the fly, like so:

```
var dots = new Array();
for(var i=0;i<5;i++) {
    var $dot = $('<div class="dot" />');
    $dot.css({ top: dotPosition_Y[i], left: dotPosition_X[i]});
    $dot.appendTo('#map');
}
```

I made a working demo for you, including a way to change colors, here:

http://jsfiddle.net/eCEfd/

Comment: Thats exactly what i had in mind (not the code, i really did'nthave a clue how to get it going)